# generic in C# State <T>

Tags: generics

I create a class:

```
public class State<T>
{
    private T state; 
    private double cost;    
    private State<T> cameFrom; 
    public State(T state)    // CTOR
    {
        this.state = state;
        cost = 0;
        cameFrom = null;
    }
```

then I opened an interface:

```
public interface ISearchable
{
    State<T> getInitialState();
    State<T> getGoalState();
    List<State<T>> getAllPossibleStates(State<T> s);
}
```

And it mark me on the interface the following error: 
The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Why?

How can I fix it?

Comment: You must make the methods generic, or the interface generic, so either `State<T> getInitialState<T>();` or `public interface ISearchable<T>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know how to resolve the type `T` in the interface methods. You need to make either the interface or the methods generic as well:

```
public interface ISearchable<T>
```

Or:

```
public interface ISearchable
{
    State<T> GetInitialState<T>();
    State<T> GetGoalState<T>();
    List<State<T>> GetAllPossibleStates<T>(State<T> s);
}
```

By the way, the usual convention in C# is to use initial upper case for method names.

Comment: Or the methods, but probably the interface.